# How to host web server without tunneling or port forwarding?

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver, http, tunnel, isp

I have a local web server that I would like to make public but our ISP doesn't allow port forwarding and conventional tunneling services (ngrok, proxylocal, etc.) are much slower than port forwarding is. Any other way to host a server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your router support DMZ hosting? if so, stripping and locking down the host and placing it in the DMZ should be faster than port forwarding anyway. I am curious however, how your ISP prevents port forwards. that may imply that it is impossible to run a server that accepts unsolicited incomming connection requests on their net at all.

Comment: The ISP-provided modem (which cannot be replace) disallows ports to be forwarded.

Comment: so install a router on the inside port of the modem and configure the port forwarding on it. if the modem is disallowing unsolicited connection attempts, then there is no way you can run the server without a reverse tunnel anyway.

Comment: "Any other way to host a server?" Yup - change ISPs, or host your website someplace else.

Comment: Do you need to allow friends or strangers? Windows or Linux? Fixed ip or dynamic? One shot or regularly?

Comment: Strangers, Windows or Linux, Fixed IP or Dynamic, and Regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. If your ISP will not allow you to forward ports (technically or otherwise), then you *must* use a tunnel (or find a new ISP).

For tunneling, you want to use a VPN; You might have to pay a monthly fee to find one that provides you with acceptable performance. You should be able to find a good VPN for USD$10/mo or less.

Depending on how your ISP routes traffic, tunneling might even make it *faster*.

Comment: But careful: Most VPNs are for outbound access only. You’d need one that either allocates a dedicated IP or forwards a fixed port at a fixed IP. If IPv6 is acceptable, you can get those for free with a tunnel broker.